# Nodejs , Redis,Sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, redis

I have a nodejs app which reads data from redis and I am unable to push it into socket. In the c.write(message) part, if I hardcode(example c.write('hello') ,the messages are being put to the socket but when i put it as c.write(message), nothing is going to the socket. Thanks in advance,

```
var net = require('net');
var split = require('split');
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();


var server = net.createServer(function(c) {

    console.log('client connected');
    c.on('end', () => {
        console.log('client disconnected');
    });

    redis.subscribe('test-channel');

    redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
        console.log(message);
        c.write(message);
        c.pipe(c);
    });
});

server.on('error', (err) => {
    throw err;
});
server.listen(3005, 'localhost', () => {
    console.log('server bound');
});
```

Comment: What are you getting when printing console.log(message)  ?

Comment: Published messages from redis. @professionallyme86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answer.

Just add below lines to your code :

```
var message_redis = message+'\r'+'\n';
c.write(message_redis);
```